# Exception from call with stored procedure iBATIS

Tags: java, sql, ibatis

I were assigned to solve an incident in someone elses application.

But, the application uses a sqlMap and Stored procedure with iBATIS and I have never worked with this before.

This is what I have so far:

```
public void createItemInDb() {

    try {
        System.out.println("status: " + this.getStatus());
        System.out.println("weight: " + this.getWeight());
        System.out.println("node name: " + this.getNodeName());
        System.out.println("node ui: " + this.getNodeUi());

        SqlMapClient sqlMap = AppSqlMapClient.getSqlMapInstance();
        sqlMap.queryForObject("createItem", this);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

//sqlMap in xml file

```
<parameterMap class="item" id="createItemMap">
    <parameter property="nodeName" jdbcType="VARCHAR" mode="IN" />
    <parameter property="status" jdbcType="INTEGER" mode="IN" />
    <parameter property="weight" jdbcType="INTEGER" mode="IN" />
    <parameter property="nodeUi" jdbcType="INTEGER" mode="INOUT" />

</parameterMap>

<procedure id="createItem" parameterMap="createItemMap">
    {call CREATEITEM (?,?,?,?)}
</procedure>
```

I am having this exception:

```
--- The error occurred while executing query procedure.
--- Check the {call CREATEITEM (?,?,?,?)}.
--- Check the SQL Statement (preparation failed).
--- Cause: java.sql.SQLException: [SQL0204] CREATEITEM in *N type *N not found.
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: [SQL0204] CREATEITEM in *N type *N not found.
        at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.statement.GeneralStatement.executeQueryWithCallback(GeneralStatement.java:185)
        at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.mapping.statement.GeneralStatement.executeQueryForObject(GeneralStatement.java:104)
        at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapExecutorDelegate.queryForObject(SqlMapExecutorDelegate.java:565)
        at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapExecutorDelegate.queryForObject(SqlMapExecutorDelegate.java:540)
        at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapSessionImpl.queryForObject(SqlMapSessionImpl.java:106)
        at com.ibatis.sqlmap.engine.impl.SqlMapClientImpl.queryForObject(SqlMapClientImpl.java:84)
```

I do not even understand what this part means:

CREATEITEM in *N type *N not found.

What does *N stand for?

Where can I find the Stored procedures? CREATEITEM can not be found in the applications files anywhere else?

Thnx

Answer (score 0):

The stored procedure is in the database, you have to connect to the database with a database client and check the code of the stored procedure (maybe it's PL/SQL code).

The error "CREATEITEM in *N type *N not found." maybe is caused by the return type of the stored procedure. Are you sure that it's an integer?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Someone at the IT-department had managed to erase all our stored procedures. This were the cause of the exception and why I couldnt find it anywhere. Luckily we had a recent back up and it is now all solved.